# CrossValidator tuning spark ML failing on params "An extraneous Param was found" on model save

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml, apache-spark-2.0

I am running spark ml cross validation with regParam on logistic regression as part of the paramGrid.

```
val paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder()
    .addGrid(lr.regParam, Array(0.1, 0.01))
    .build()

 val validator = new CrossValidator()
  .setEstimator(estimator)
  .setEvaluator(evaluator)
  .setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid)
  .setNumFolds(3)
```

estimator here has regParam included as part of the params. 
Sample code for saving the model:

```
class MyModelWriter(instance: MyModel[T])extends MLWriter {

  override protected def saveImpl(path: String): Unit = {
    new DefaultParamsWriter(instance).save(path)
    instance.model.save(new Path(path, s"nameOfMofel").toString)
  }
}
```

Mymodel does include the regParam in the params.

```
MyModel extends HasRegParam
```

When I call model.save(path) this is the exception I am getting:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: ValidatorParams save requires all Params in estimatorParamMaps to apply to this ValidatorParams, its Estimator, or its Evaluator. An extraneous Param was found: logreg_2fb5fdbe5012__regParam
>           at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
>           at org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.ValidatorParams$$anonfun$validateParams$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ValidatorParams.scala:110)
>           at org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.ValidatorParams$$anonfun$validateParams$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ValidatorParams.scala:109)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>           at org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.ValidatorParams$$anonfun$validateParams$1.apply(ValidatorParams.scala:109)
>           at org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.ValidatorParams$$anonfun$validateParams$1.apply(ValidatorParams.scala:108)
>           at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
>           at org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.ValidatorParams$.validateParams(ValidatorParams.scala:108)
>           at org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidatorModel$CrossValidatorModelWriter.(CrossValidator.scala:257)
>           at org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidatorModel.write(CrossValidator.scala:242)
>           at org.apache.spark.ml.util.MLWritable$class.save(ReadWrite.scala:157)
>           at org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidatorModel.save(CrossValidator.scala:210)
>           at com.criteo.lookalike.sink.Sinks$$anonfun$SavePipelineParam1$1.apply(Sinks.scala:111

The code for ValidatorParams.scala at L105 says

> // Check to make sure all Params apply to this estimator.  Throw an error if any do not.

As per this its making sure that the param in estimatorMap i.e. regParam in this case is present in estimator/evaluator which in this case is indeed present in Mymodel above.

Can anyone please tell if my understanding is right and if yes, what could be causing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved for this exact error.

When you add a grid, try passing a Param instance instead; and, when instantiating the Param, match it to the documented param type as you'd find under https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/...

For example, in `RandomForestRegressor` there is `numTrees: IntParam`.

Therefore I build the param grid as follows...

```
val rf = new RandomForestRegressor()
.{set...()} // (pseudocode)

val numTrees = new IntParam(rf, "numTrees", "Number of trees to train (>= 1) (default = 20)")

// for fun/preference, i make numTrees[Int] increase as does the area of a circle
val numTreesValues = (for (n <- 3 to 20 by 3) yield (math.Pi * math.pow(n, 2)).toInt)

val paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder()
.addGrid(numTrees, numTreesValues)
.build()
```

Try passing the estimator into a param, then the param and the values into `.addGrid`

My validator then looks like this...

```
val cv = new CrossValidator()
.setEstimator(rf)
.setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid)
.{set...()}
```